# Set cache-control for aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-headers

I have an asp.net web site and I would like the client browser to cache the HTML output of aspx pages once it gets them.
From reading around I found out that IIS7 does not support this out-of-the-box, so I added the following code to the `OnLoad` event of my main master page:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(dt);
    Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(dt.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks));

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

With this I still get the following in the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 14:25:03 GMT
Content-Length: 10201
```

Maybe I did something a long time ago to override this, but I can't, for the life of me remember if and what I did. Not finding any info on this when searching Google makes me think that maybe `cache-control` for aspx pages is not a good idea... but I need this in order for cloudfront (a CDN) to allow whole site delivery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the IIS pipeline (I have yet to find out where), no cache headers were set. In my master page, before setting the cache headers I wanted to use, I added the following code `Response.ClearHeaders();` This might not be a good solution for everyone, since you might have some headers you need in the response already, but in my case it did the trick.